# apply custom function to multiple spark dataframes taking dataframe as a parameter

Tags: dataframe, lambda, pyspark

All,

I have a requirement where I am dealing with 3 large dataframes, aDf, bDf and cDf and I want to "trim" string columns to remove blank spaces.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim, col
for col_name,col_dtype in aDf.dtypes:
    if col_dtype == "string":
       aDf = aDf.withColumn(col_name, trim(col(col_name)))
    else:
       aDf = aDf.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name))
        
for col_name,col_dtype in bDf.dtypes:
    if col_dtype == "string":
       bDf = bDf.withColumn(col_name, trim(col(col_name)))
    else:
       bDf = bDf.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name))
        
for col_name,col_dtype in cDf.dtypes:
    if col_dtype == "string":
       cDf = cDf.withColumn(col_name, trim(col(col_name)))
    else:
       cDf = cDf.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name))
```

Is there a better and an efficient way to handle this simple transformation. There are close to 40 columns and approx. 100 MM rows in every dataframe.

While this works, I have a feeling that even the dataframe can be parameterized. That way, the code becomes even more generic.

Any pointers please..thanks

Comment: This [link](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-36e97896c378) will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the code but time taken will still be the same

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

aDf = trimDF(aDf)
bDf = trimDF(bDf)
cDf = trimDF(cDf)

def trimDF(df):
    df = reduce(lambda df, col: df.withColumn(col[0],f.trim(f.col(col[0]))) if col[1]=='string' else df.withColumn(col[0],f.col(col[0])), df.dtypes, df)
    return df
```